# Make a column NULL for insert and NOT NULL for update

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, nullable

This is something that I stumbled across multiple projects, and I feel I'm reinventing the wheel every time:

I have a table that stores user data. Whenever the user is created, I create one row on the table. This row has several NULL fields on creation, because the user just informed some critical information (and other non-critical info is going to be filled later).

But, when the user completes the filling of the data, I want to enforce this cols to be NOT NULL.

Is there any way to make a column NULL for INSERT, but NOT NULL for UPDATE that does not involves triggers? Or any other clever solution?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you would like to share us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE users ( regular_column SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
                     smart_column SOMETYPE NULL,
                     completed ENUM('no', 'yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
                     CHECK ((completed = 'no') OR (smart_column IS NOT NULL)) );
```

> This row has several NULL fields on creation, because the user just informed some critical information (and other non-critical info is going to be filled later).

In this moment `completed = 'no'`, CHECK constraint is TRUE, `smart_column` may be NULL.

> when the user completes the filling of the data, I want to enforce this cols to be NOT NULL.

In this moment `completed = 'yes'`, and CHECK constraint does not allow NULL value in `smart_column`.

I.e. setting `completed` column to `'yes'` fixes `smart_column` - you may alter it but cannot set it to NULL. And you cannot set `completed` to `'yes'` until `smart_column` is set to a value.

Comment: Special thanks for the CHECK statement that makes very easy to add new columns to it!

Answer (score 0):

If you use column options in your `CREATE TABLE` statement, there's no way a column can be both NULLable and NOT NULL. There's no way to distinguish between inserts and updates.

The alternative could be to let the column be nullable, but add a trigger on UPDATE that throws an exception (called a SIGNAL in MySQL terminology) if the column is still NULL after the update.

Here's a quick demo:

```
mysql> create table mytable (id int primary key, x int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> delimiter //

mysql> create trigger notnullonupdate before update on mytable
    -> for each row 
    -> begin
    -> if NEW.x IS NULL then
    -> signal sqlstate '45000'
    -> set message_text = 'x must be updated to non-NULL value';
    -> end if;
    -> end//

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> insert into mytable set id = 42, x = null;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> update mytable set id = 42;
ERROR 1644 (45000): x must be updated to non-NULL value
```

Even though this is possible, it's kind of a lot of work.

Most developers would just handle this by writing application code to ensure the value is not null before executing an update. Of course the risk of that is if you forget one of the cases in your app that does an update, or if someone does an ad hoc update in the mysql client, it could cause your data to be in an invalid state and you wouldn't know it.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I'm currently writing application code for the validation, as you said. But I think this is the wrong solution in the long term. Your trigger answer does work as intended, but I'm marking @Akina as correct because it does this on table creation syntax